# Where did the name "T-800" come from?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

After watching *The Terminator* and *Terminator 2*, I can't find any reference to Schwarzenegger's Terminator being called the "T-800". Yet I distinctly remember in promotional material, computer games, etc. at the time, he was called the "T-800". (He refers to himself as a "Cyberdyne Systems Model 101" at one point)

So my question is, where is it mentioned that he's called the "T-800"? Please limit the answers to the first two movies - while this name/sku may be mentioned from the third movie onwards, he was definitely being called the "T-800" by sources (out-of-universe) before then.

Answer (score 31):

There is a [deleted scene](http://www.hopeofthefuture.net/deletedscenes/t2del16.html) included in the "Skynet Edition" Director's Cut of Terminator 2 in which The Terminator sees himself in a mirror while he runs a diagnostic. Whilst doing so, you can see he is a **Cyberdyne Systems Series 800 Model 101 Version 2.4** Terminator.

[image]

Additionally, there is an [omitted scene](http://www.hopeofthefuture.net/deletedscenes/t2omit13.html) that was removed from the movie entirely where Sarah, John and Arnie end up at the ranch of one Travis Gant. There is some dialogue between Sarah and Gant as she tries to persuade him to help, then:

> SARAH: Tell him what you are.
>
> TERMINATOR: Series 800 terminator. Model 101. Cyborg tactical infiltrator.

Again identifying him as a **Series 800 Model 101**.

Comment: When does he look at himself in the mirror during the movie?

Comment: Jack B Nimble. This scene is only in the director's cut version of the film. The Skynet edition, as it's called.

Comment: Yep, I've edited my answer to clarify that "Night Repairs" is a deleted scene present in the Director's cut, but not the theatrical cut, and that "Gant Ranch" is a scene that was omitted from the movie entirely.

Comment: So where does the "T" come from... or should they be "800-T"..... :P

Comment: I assume the "T" stands for "Terminator"

Comment: I was going to leave a comment earlier about the T "obviously" standing for "Terminator," but then I thought "naaah, that doesn't really need to be explicitly stated, does it? Surely everyone understands that."  Good ol' internet, always proving me wrong.

Answer (score 14):

The Series 800 name is mentioned twice in the [script for *Terminator 2: Judgement Day*](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html):

> TILT UP, revealing a humanoid machine holding a massive battle rifle. It looks like a CHROME SKELETON... a high-tech Death figure.  It is the endoskeleton of a Series 800 terminator.  Its glowing red eyes compassionlessly sweep the dead terrain, hunting.
>
> ...
>
> We realize now that the cop is a terminator too.  We don't know the details yet, but let's call him the T-1000 (since that's what he is). A newer model than the one we've come to know so well (the 800 Series "Arnold").  This guy's a prototype... and he's got quite a few surprises.

Additionally, the Terminator Wiki's article on the T-800 mentions in the [references](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_800#References) that the HUD identifies it as a Series 800 in *Terminator 2* (I'm not sure if this is only in the deleted scene mentioned in [@DisturbedNeo's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166199/31936) or if it also appears in another scene as well). The references also note that James Cameron referred to both the Series 800 and 1000 Terminators in the *Terminator 2* commentary. (The commentary is not available to me at this time so I can't confirm.)

The [Terminator Wiki's article on the Model 101](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cyberdyne_Systems_Model_101) also has a screenshot from the *Terminator 2* teaser trailer showing the Series 800 designation:

[image: Series 800 screenshot from Terminator 2 teaser trailer]

Note that "Model 101" refers to the human appearance of the Terminator (Arnold Schwarzenegger) rather than the model (series) of the endoskeleton. Other models have different appearances, such as the [Future Terminator](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Future_Terminator) ([Model 102](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-808)) portrayed by Franco Columbu.